# closing windows ui message popup

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I m displaying an popup message for my windows 8 application using javascript like below

```
var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("No internet connection has been found.");
msg.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Try again", commandInvokedHandler));
msg.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Close", commandInvokedHandler));
msg.defaultCommandIndex = 0;
msg.cancelCommandIndex = 1;
msg.showAsync();
```

Now I want to close the popup message programatically after some timeinterval as the user has not given any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is a hide/dismiss/cancel command for that kind of message popup. The cancel command is invoked when pressing the escape key on you're keyboard. Thees kinds of messages is not intended for information purpose. You should instead use a "FlyOut".

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Define a flyout in HTML as you wish -->
<div id="informationFlyout" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Flyout">
    <p>
        Some informative text
    </p>
</div>

<!-- an anchor for the flyout, where it should be displayed -->
<div id="flyoutAnchor"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
    // Get an anchor for the flyout
    var flyoutAnchor = document.getElementById("flyoutAnchor"); 

    // Show flyout at anchor
    document.getElementById("informationFlyout").winControl.show(flyoutAnchor);
```

To dismiss the flyout after a set amount of time you could just do a setTimeout and hide in you're code:

```
// execute this code after 2000ms
setTimeout(function () {

    // Fetch the flyout
    var flyout = document.getElementById("informationFlyout"); // Get the flyout from HTML

    // Check if the element still exists in DOM
    if (flyout) 
        flyout.winControl.hide(); // Dismiss the flyout

}, 2000);
```

Read more about the FlyOut-popups [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211726.aspx)

Comment: This is wrong because there is infact a cancel. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There is infact a cancel that you can call on the object returned by the showAsync method, first call the messageDialog in this way:

```
var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("No internet connection has been found.");
var asyncOperation = msg.showAsync();
```

then whenever you want you can call:

```
asyncOperation.cancel();
```

and the messageDialog will be dismissed.